# Connect aws-appsync with nextjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, react-apollo, next.js, aws-appsync

I am trying to connect aws-appsync with a nextjs app. I can't figure out how to do that efficiently.

I have tried using the apollo example in the next js examples on github but did not succeed. I was confused since appsync does not use in-memory cache in the examples on its documentation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use Apollo with Next? If so then maybe try disabling the offline feature of the AWS AppSync client by setting `disableOffline` to true:

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  disableOffline: true,
  url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: appSyncConfig.region,
  auth: {
    type: appSyncConfig.authenticationType,
    apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey,
  }
});
```